# How to get started with writing a program that consists of three classes

Tags: java

Write a program that consists of three classes.  The first class will be the actual program.

The second class will simply convert a string to lower case.

The third class will have three methods: I have been working on this assignment but i need some help. All my previous assignments have been only in one string. So i'm not sure how to get started with this. I will list what i have tried so far.

import java.io.*;

public class A3BE2300780 
 {

BufferedReader in = getReader ("input.txt");

```
   private static class LowerCase {
public static String convertToLowerCase(String input) {
if (input==null) return "";
return input.toLowerCase();
}
}

   public static class ThirdStringManip{
 //This method will trim the white space from the 
 //beginning and end of the string
    public static String trimmed(String s){
        if (s == null){
            return "";
        }
        return s.trim();
    }
    //This method will return a trimmed string of size len
    public static String trimmed(String s, int len){
        String retVal = ThirdStringManip.trimmed(s);
        if (len > retVal.length()){
            len = retVal.length();
        }
        return retVal.substring(0,len);
    }
    //This method will convert all double spaces to a single space
    public static String squeeze(String s){
        return s.replace("  ", " ");
    }
}

    //This method will read strings from the input file 
//and perform manipulations on each string. The results of the 
//manipulations are displayed in the text area
private void displayManipulatedStrings() throws Exception{


    while(loop)
    {
     //Get the next line in the file
        String curString = s.nextLine();
        //Trim and Squeeze
        System.out.print ( "Trim & Squeeze: " + ThirdStringManip.squeeze(ThirdStringManip.trimmed(curString)) + "\n");
        //Trim, Squeeze, and Shorten to 10 characters
        System.out.print ( "Trim, Squeeze, Shorten to 10: " + ThirdStringManip.trimmed(ThirdStringManip.squeeze(ThirdStringManip.trimmed(curString)),10) + "\n");
        //Trim, Squeeze, lower-case and shorten to 20 characters
        System.out.print ( "Trim, Squeeze, Shorten to 20, lower-case: " + toLower(ThirdStringManip.trimmed(ThirdStringManip.squeeze(ThirdStringManip.trimmed(curString)),20)) + "\n");
        System.out.print ( "\n");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: welcome to SO! to get the most help state what is your problem and provide as much information as possible. For your questions - what IDE do you use ? what have you tried ?

Comment: I'm using  net bean. I'm still new at this hence my reason for seeking help. I post the whole question as not to leave anything out in what i'm asking.

Comment: public static String convertToLowerCase(String input) {
         if (input==null) return "";
         return input.toLowerCase();
     }
    String s1 = "ABC";
    String s2 = LowerCase.convertToLowerCase(s1);

Comment: This is what i had to start off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so ... Some JAVA book & online tutorials will help a lot...

To start

Main class is where your main method is. So create a new empty class and add your main method to it.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
   //inside you can put some logic
}
```

Create another class and i.e StringConversion and insert a simple method iniside for example

```
class StringConversion { 
    private String lowerCaseString = "";   
    public String stringConversion(String somestring) {
        lowerCaseString = somestring.toLowerCase();
        return this.lowerCaseString;
    }
}
```

Then create a third class with whatever methods you require

In your main method you can do

```
StringConversion lowerCaseString = new StringConversion();
String lowerCase = lowerCaseString.stringConversion("SOME STRING");
```

Then you can just print out the lowerCase string ;)

**ALSO NOTE: MEGA ULTRA UBER IMPORTANT**

When asking question on StackOverflow do not ASK US to do something for you, You have to show effort and show us what you tried by either explaining nicely or showing to us what have you done and why it didn't work. You can not just dump a homework question and pray that someone will do it for you. it just doesn;t work that way, and often you will find your questions to be locked and closed

Comment: thank you for your input, i will keep that in mindpublic static String convertToLowerCase(String input) {
         if (input==null) return "";
         return input.toLowerCase();
     }
    String s1 = "ABC";
    String s2 = LowerCase.convertToLowerCase(s1);

Comment: public static String convertToLowerCase(String input) {
         if (input==null) return "";
         return input.toLowerCase();
     }
    String s1 = "ABC";
    String s2 = LowerCase.convertToLowerCase(s1);

Comment: @Downvoter ? any explanation why ??

Comment: @user3477356 Please delete these comments and edit your questions accordingly. Comments are not designed for posting code but to comment on given question/answer. To show additional code please update your question and we can help you out